# Snap during transform can not snap to what I want

Tags: vertices

Why can't I snap the point I chose to the target point. 
I tried for a long time to do this, but no use!

Could some help me? Thanks !

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, blender doesnt work that way...(out of the box) But you can get addons. Or you can snap the origin point to the 3D cursor.

Comment: at first i use the origin and 3d cursor function,but it is too slow for this simple action.thank you friend!

Comment: But if you join the two meshes into a single mesh, it acts better in edit mode. You can select one face and press (Ctrl+L) to select just on of the objects.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish, the question is extremely unclear.

Comment: oh,it can works,thanks,join them into a single mesh is good way to do this.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ thanks man ,i just want to move a object to nearby another one with there vertex superposition，snap can do this perfectly，but as i post ，try a long time but still have some confuse  with the snap.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ http://i.imgur.com/O9UoX1u.jpg

Comment: Blender does work that way. Snap During transform can snap objects and you can select between modes to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of complex objects [Snap During Transform](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/precision/snap.html#transform-snapping) might not guess where should be the vertex you'd like to snap. If using *Closest* method while in Object mode, it will depend on object's bounds. If using that method in Edit mode, it will use nearest vertex to snap to.
To snap object's vertex (and whole mesh following it) to vertex of another object use Edit mode (without any joining).

Enter Edit mode for object being snapped, select all and activate Snap During Transform:

- To implicitly snap desired vertex and make mesh follow it use *Active* mode;
- To snap the closest vertex to object being snapped to and make whole mesh follow snapped vertex use *Closest* method.

[image: GIF snapping mesh in Edit mode]

Note that depending on further actions with the object you might want to change its origin.

Answer (score 6):

Solution in object mode :

- Add an empty
- Set snap to vertex option
- Grab your empty to the needed vertex of the mesh to be moved
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the mesh to be moved additionally to the empty
- Then grab them both to the destination

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks man!Maybe I am too late,but thanks!

Comment: A bit of explanation about the reason it can't work without the empty, and the role the empty plays, would be useful.

Comment: @mins, the empty is a "one point" element which helps to aim one vertex in the target mesh.

Answer (score 4):

Since @lemon's answer, in 2.8+, we have been able to drag the cursor around, opening another possible workflow, also without having to go into Edit Mode.

The '*Center*' snap-from entry in the snap settings refers to the active Transform Center / Pivot Point, as set in the header dropdown. This can be the 3D Cursor. So, with the Transform Pivot Point set to 3D Cursor, snap-from set to '*Center*', and snap-to set to '*Vertex*', you can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> - <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> activate the cursor tool.

- Drag-snap the cursor to the desired source vertex
- <kbd>G</kbd> Drag-snap the object, snapping where the cursor *was* at the beginning of the move, to the desired target vertex.

[image]

Comment: @glades Glad that helps! Funnily enough, I prefer lemon's way, maybe because I'm a bit of an old-timer in more primitive packages. In CAD-like work, I tend to have a collection of home-made jigs lying around: angles, lengths, orientations, arcs, stashed in simple objects/Empties.