# How to define own snapping points?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, add-on, snapping

can someone tell me if its possible to define own "snapping points"?
I know the poissibility to snap to Volume, Face, Edge, Vertex and Increment - but what i need is the following:

I made a small library of parts (e.g. Legos, metal construction, scaffold, etc) these small parts i would link to my actual scene. But there are just some parts which fit together. aligning these parts manually is quite boring and time consumpting. So what i need is a way to define some kind of point/vertex/empty on every part where it would snap into each other. Maybe like some magnetic area...

Do you know what i mean? How can i realize it? Is there a addon i missed?

Thanks in advance,
j

Comment: something like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58022/snap-during-transform-can-not-snap-to-what-i-want/58097#58097 ?

Comment: On first sight not exactly but an interesting alternative attempt, I'll give it a try tonight...