# How to perfectly position these faces into this slot / area? (no gaps)

Tags: transforms, edit-mode, faces

I am trying to fit and join (connect with the rest of the vertices, so no holes) this selection of faces into an empty area.

The slot / empty area is the exact same size as this selection of faces, meaning it should "fit in" perfectly.

[image]

However, there are tiny gaps; the positioning is imperfect. Once I get it this group of faces to position perfectly so there are not even tiny gaps, then I should be able to remove vertex doubles and get what I want. But the hard part is... getting it to position perfectly. How can I preposition perfectly to ensure there are no gaps?

[image]

Comment: Use the snapping tools. Press `Ctrl` while transforming to snap to existing geometry

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is what happens when I try holding `Ctrl` while transforming https://gyazo.com/0e4483a9c5ed722315d7b5b286272e08

Comment: Switch snapping mode to vertex in the 3D view header, bellow the viewport

Comment: Changing to vertex snapping, causes nothing at all to happen when using `Ctrl`.

Comment: Make sure You have *Vertex* and *Closest* in the menu to the right. Try turning on the magnet icon to the left

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58022/snap-during-transform-can-not-snap-to-what-i-want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the snapping tools, specifically the vertex snapping mode, as others have said in the comments. The snapping tools take a little getting used to, but are really quite powerful. As I have noticed when using vertex snapping, Blender seems to take one vertex from your selection and try to snap it to the positions of others not in your selection while all other selected verts move in relation to the snapping vertex. Unfortunately I don't think you can specify which vertex will do the snapping, not exactly. You can however almost always change how the surfaces will attempt to snap together by moving the objects in relation to each other before hand.

The key is first placing your object so it can find a good snap, then moving it with snap mode. Using the ctrl key is really helpful for this.

For example:
If you are trying to snap cube A to above cube B, but cube A is somewhere off to the right side of cube B, Blender will only want to snap cube A on to the left side of cube B. However if you first move cube A somewhere above cube B, you should be able to snap cube A down onto the top of cube B.