# Move and snap a group of objects

Tags: groups, snapping

When I have selected the group and click on the part that I want to move and snap with another stand alone object in object mode, I just get one of the objects in the group, the rest is left behind. Is there another way to move and snap a group?

The snap setting is vertex and closet, despite that, it will not snap completely, it's a distance that looks like 1 cm. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58022/snap-during-transform-can-not-snap-to-what-i-want/58097#58097

Comment: See lemon's great answer bout snapping, you may also be misusing groups or maybe misunderstand how they work. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311#47311 for more details about how to use groups