# Snapping to vertex doesn't work for unknown reasons

Tags: vertices, snapping

Sometimes I try snapping vertices to the closest neighbour but it doesn't work as the object is always off. I think I'm missing something. I applied all transformations already and the origin is at center. What could it be?
[image]

In this gif I'm trying to snap the angled pole to the bottom pole's low right (then left) corner with vertex snap. But as you can see it is off in all cases, even when I try to snap to vertices of different objects.

Comment: What are you trying to snap to what, in this .gif?

Comment: I'm trying to snap the angled pole to the bottom right corner of the lying pole with vertex snap so that the pole is the equivalent of the one on the other edge. But as you can see it won't snap correctly.

Comment: Yes indeed that works @lemon! Thank you! Although it would be nice if it worked too in object mode :)

Comment: @glades, it works: in 2.8+ just check the "snap with" "center" option in the snap panel.

Comment: I'm with @lemon here, his method with the Empty is simple, and gives good feedback to the user. Since we've been able to drag the cursor around, [another way has become available](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191417/35559). I've put the answer there, with lemon's, because this question may be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: OMG @Robin Betts that is the missing piece! Thank you so much, that will accelerate everything. I just need to set a shortkey for moving the 3d cursor :D